# Very Difficult Indexing Challenge: Do This in One Line

Tags: performance, numpy, optimization, indexing, python-itertools

I have data that has N rows with K elements per row. Each element has an integer value (index) between 0 and INDEX_SIZE.

I want to count for every two indexes:

- n11[i,j]: in how many rows does index i appear and j appear together.
- n10[i,j]: in how many rows does index i appear and j does not.
- n01[i,j]: in how many rows does index i not appear and j appears.
- n00[i,j]: in how many rows neither index i nor index j appear.

I'd like to do the following code with indexing, much much faster:

```
N = 10
K = 5
INDEX_SIZE = 100

# Random seed to get the same values every time:
np.random.seed(100)
data = np.random.random_integers(0, INDEX_SIZE-1, (N,K))

# These are for the good values:
n11 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))
n10 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))
n01 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))
n00 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))

for id1 in range(INDEX_SIZE):
    for id2 in range(INDEX_SIZE):
        for i in range(data.shape[0]):
            if id1 in data[i,:] and id2 in data[i,:]:
                n11[id1,id2] += 1
            if id1 in data[i,:] and id2 not in data[i,:]:
                n10[id1,id2] += 1
            if id1 not in data[i,:] and id2 in data[i,:]:
                n01[id1,id2] += 1
            if id1 not in data[i,:] and id2 not in data[i,:]:
                n00[id1,id2] += 1

# These are for the indexing code:
n11v2 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))
n10v2 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))
n01v2 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))
n00v2 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))

# Code with indexing here:
#

def diff(a,b):
    return np.mean(np.abs(a-b))

print('Diff(n11,n11v2) = '+str(diff(n11,n11v2)))
print('Diff(n10,n10v2) = '+str(diff(n10,n10v2)))
print('Diff(n01,n01v2) = '+str(diff(n01,n01v2)))
print('Diff(n00,n00v2) = '+str(diff(n00,n00v2)))
```

How do I do this over all the rows at once? I believe the for loop can be replaced in one line per counter (so 4 lines in total). I tried itertools and looking up np.indices but could not make any progress. I can easily do this for a single row with a 2D boolean mask (iterating only over rows). But this is too slow.

EDIT: fixed random integer generation

Comment: Can you add some dummy INDEX_SIZE array and the final array as what the result should be ?

Comment: What are typical values for N, K and INDEX_SIZE?

Comment: N ~= 1000000; K ~= 150; INDEX_SIZE ~= 500. I cannot really run this code with those numbers... I run it with N=10.... I will add a test data and output result for a small input in a few minutes.

Comment: Added with verification of result (this code takes only a few seconds to run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using sparse matrices. It's not one line per output. (It's two but I'm saving four lines by not using the preallocation.) It's reasonably fast, though (~1 min for `N=10^6, K=150, INDEX_SIZE=500`).

```
## These are for the indexing code:
#n11v2 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))
#n10v2 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))
#n01v2 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))
#n00v2 = np.zeros((INDEX_SIZE,INDEX_SIZE))

# Code with indexing here:
from scipy import sparse
spD = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones(data.size, np.int32), data.ravel(),
                         np.arange(0, N*K+1, K, np.int32)), (N, INDEX_SIZE))
spD.sum_duplicates()
spD.data = np.ones_like(spD.data)
n11v2 = (spD.T@spD).A
m = np.einsum('ii->i', n11v2)[:, None]
n10v2 = m - n11v2
n01v2 = n10v2.T
n00v2 = N + n11v2 - m - m.T
```

Comment: The line: n11v2 = (spD.T@spD).A -- kills the kernel for me

Comment: @user1581390 What, with the small example?

Comment: N = 5
K = 5
INDEX_SIZE = 100

Comment: @user1581390 I should have mentioned I've replaced the line that generates `data` with `data = np.random.randint(0, INDEX_SIZE, (N, K))`. I'd argue that is more appropriate. `randn` creates normally distributed values, those can be negative and of arbitrary size. Looks like these out-of-bounds values are enough to kill scipy...

Comment: Can you put data back there?

Comment: You'd have to update your question. Currently it says _Each element has an integer value (index) between 0 and INDEX_SIZE._ This is not true, if `randn` is used, so you'd have to clarify how you want negative indices and indices >= INDEX_SIZE handled.

Comment: Oh now I get it, I was the one who did the random wrong! Testing again...

Comment: It works with random indexes. As for the real data, it works only after I do data = np.unique(data,axis=1). And I don't understand why. Doing that operation doesn't remove any double indexes, it only changes the order slightly.

Comment: Okay got it, this code alters the variable 'data', so I made a copy at the beginning, Works great! thank you!